# Access denied error when trying to load a package on Intergration Services

Tags: ssis, authentication

I am getting an error when I try and upload a import an ssis project onto our server. The server only has integration and reporting services installed as the live sql server is on another server. I log onto the integration service fine but as soon as I try to right click the MSDB folder to import a package I get the error listed at the end of this question. I have added my local user account as an administrator on the server where the Integration Service is installed and I have added the administrators group to the security permissions for MsDtsServer in component services. Any help with this would be appreciated.

### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Failed to retrieve data for this request. (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoEnum)

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Login timeout expired
An error has occurred while establishing a connection to the server. When connecting to SQL Server 2005, this failure may be caused by the fact that under the default settings SQL Server does not allow remote connections.
Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [2].  (Microsoft SQL Native Client)

---

BUTTONS:

### OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem recently. It was a little tricky to figure out.

Here is a nice link from MSDN on how to hack, err, I mean fix it.

[Configuring the Integration Services Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137789(SQL.90).aspx)

> "To manage packages that are stored in a named instance or a remote instance of the Database Engine, or in multiple instances of the Database Engine, you have to modify the configuration file." - MSDN

Thanks Microsoft??

To be more specific, you need to edit this file on your server:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\DTS\Binn\ MsDtsSrvr.ini.xml

Change:

```
<ServerName>.</ServerName>
```

to

```
<ServerName>ServerName\InstanceName</ServerName>
```

Save. and reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Is your server set up to accept remote sql connections? Maybe check your firewall on the server to check that all the SSIS ports are allowed through, and also check in the SQL Surface Area Configuration tool to make sure all the services are set up to allow remote connections.